# Android Image Zoom and Pan in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-image, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have implemented Image zoom  and pan following the samples and articles in net and both zoom and pan are working fine on KitKat but on Jelly bean neither zoom nor pan works its a freeze'd image.

```
currentMatrix.postScale(temp, temp, 0, 0);
setImageMatrix(this.currentMatrix);
```

Is there anything to be done for image in case of jelly bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jelly bean i have to invalidate my image view once i set a new matrix for it.

```
ImageView.postInvalidate();
```

in kitkat no need of invaliding.